# How to restore a site root collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Totally embarrassing - a sub-site from our staging environment was imported targeting the production environment's root site collection instead of the sub-site.  Needless to say, the site is down.  I am **new** to this inherited admin role and I have a few questions.

- By 'overwriting' the root site collection, did I 'overwrite' the content?
- If not, can I perform a granular restoration to restore the earlier configuration?

I am trying my best not to perform a full config and content restoration to insure that no data was lost since the last backup - provided that the content was not lost.

Will
"newbie of the year"

Comment: The site is lost, most likely (at least if "imported" means restore of a backup made on the test environment, which is, unfortunatelly, quite common procedure). Then full restore is your only option.

Comment: Also note this question is a much better fit for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ondrej, thanks for your quick response.  I can still link to the sub-sites.  So, I will perform a granular backup on the sub-sites, perform a full farm restore, and then restore the newly created granular backups.  Is my logic correct?

Comment: I am moving this question to the Sharepoint forum.

Comment: If you have just one site collection, then yes.